# Why do my outdoor faucets only leak when the hoses are attached with the water on?

Tags: water, leaks

I have three outdoor faucets (500 series Prier) that I've replaced parts for, but they all begin to leak one place or another once I attach the hoses and turn the water on. When I detach the hoses and turn the water on without hoses attached, there are no leaks anywhere on the faucet. When I turn the water off there are no leaks either.
The only thing I can surmise is the water pressure is too strong, so the water is coming out faster than it can go through the hose. Is this feasible?
Does anyone have any other ideas now that I've replaced all the parts?
Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly are they leaking?  Pictures are good.  Most faucets should only leak from valve stem or the hose attachment.  Anywhere else usually replace the faucet.  If leaking from valve stem, tighten too much or not enough, or new parts not put in right.

Comment: Does the leak occur at the faucet with the connected hose only? If this is the case, yes, the water pressure forces the water out from the small gap in the connector. You need to either tighten the connector a little more or apply Teflon tape to close the gap.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an explanation consistent with the facts you have given:

The leak is around the stem. When the faucet is off the water cannot get to the stem because the sealing mechanism stops it.

When the faucet is on full with a hose attached, the hose causes backpressure which forces water through the stem.

When the faucet is on full with no hose attached, the water flows freely out the faucet and there is not enough backpressure to force water out around the stem.

To correct this tighten the bonnet nut if there is one. Do this with the valve open with the hose attached. Tighten in increments and observe if this is reducing the leak.